# Flask-Python: upload a csv file and use its data in the application

Tags: python, flask

I'm new in Flask and not familiar with its tools enough.
So, I'm trying to upload a CSV file to my application; in order to use its data to plot some graphs using Pygal.

This is was my attempt, but it didn't work:

```
 def upload_file():
   return render_template('upload.html')
@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file[]']
      f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
      x= np.asarray(f)
            graph = pygal.Line()
    graph.title = '% Change Coolness of programming languages over time.'
    graph.add('Graph', x[1,:])

    graph_data = graph.render_data_uri()
    return render_template("upload.html", graph_data = graph_data)
```

The HTML code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<body class="body">
      <div class="container" align="left">
            <embed type="image/svg+xml" src={{graph_data|safe}} style='max-width:1000px'/>
      </div>

            <form action = "http://localhost:5000/uploader" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name ="file" />
         <input type = "submit"/>
      </form>

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

the Error message is:

> ' ERROR: execution aborted'

and also this exclamation mark appears beside the "graph.add" line, as a space error!

[image]
anyone have an idea how do I get to the desired result?

Comment: `x= np.asarray(f)` seems strange.  `asarray` doesn't take a file.  Perhaps you should look at `genfromtxt` or even the builtin `csv` module from Python to convert your `.csv` data into a python list/etc.

Comment: Also the exclamation mark is warning that you need a space after the comma-- it's just a standard that makes the code a little more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
I just solved the problem, and actually, It was due to lack of understanding of the request method.
Simply, I determined the uploaded file path using os.path method, before I had using this path in "genfromtxt", as we usually do.

This was my solution:

```
@app.route('/upload')
def upload_file():
   return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
      data= genfromtxt(os.path.abspath(f.filename) , delimiter=',')
      graph = pygal.Line()

      if data.shape[1]==0:
          graph.add('Data', data)
      else:
          graph.add('Data', data[1,:])

      graph_data = graph.render_data_uri()
      return render_template("upload.html", graph_data = graph_data)
```